# Rails 4 not resetting authentication_token on delete session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I followed a tutorial to set up an authentication_token to work with Devise so users could sign in / out via an API. This sessions controller is supposed to override the Devise one.

sessions_controller.rb

```
def destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          super
        }
        format.json {
          user = User.find_by_authentication_token(request.headers['X-API-TOKEN'])
          if user
            user.reset_authentication_token!
            render :json => { :message => 'Session deleted.' }, :success => true, :status => 204
          else
            render :json => { :message => 'Invalid token.' }, :status => 404
          end
        }
      end
    end
```

user.rb model

```
def generate_secure_token_string
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(25).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
  end      

def generate_authentication_token
        loop do
          token = generate_secure_token_string
          break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
        end
      end

      def reset_authentication_token!
        self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
      end

def ensure_authentication_token!
    if authentication_token.blank?
      self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
    end
  end
```

It does successfully generate a token if that field is blank (it was for all existing users) but when users log in/out, the token just remains static. It seems like this defeats the purpose.

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Did you save the newly generated token to database?

Comment: @Aetherus good question. reset_authentication_token is almost identical to ensure_authentication_token -- and the latter did save a new token to the database, while 'reset' does not. i tried adding 'self.save' in that method and that did not work. maybe this is a dumb question, but it is supposed to be changing it in the database, right? http://soryy.com/blog/2014/apis-with-devise/ it doesn't seem like its adding security if it stays static.

Comment: Instead of setting self.authentication_token equal to generate_authentication_token, can you try using the update_column approach? Not sure if you require some validations but maybe something like below?

self.update_column(:authentication_token, generate_authentication_token)

When I put some bindings around the area i noticed the user's token was saved in memory but not necessarily updated in the database when using the "=" approach.